# How do I resolve a "No repository found" error when attempting to install E-P-I-C?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, epic

I have a VM running Ubuntu 14 and I downloaded Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).  I am running eclipse as root from my /opt/eclipse folder.  After adding the install url 
 http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates
then during the installation of components the following error pops up.  What is this error? How do I resolve it?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,4.0.1.201506240215-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.slf4j.impl.log4j12,1.7.2.v20131105-2200
```